# Test cells in one dataframe against those in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# From:
df1=pd.DataFrame({ 'col1':[1,3,5,7,9], 'col2':[2,4,6,8,10] } )

df2=pd.DataFrame({ 'col1':[5,5,5,5,5], 'col2':[6,6,6,6,6] } )

df3=pd.DataFrame({ 'col1':[2,2,2,2,2], 'col2':[3,3,3,3,3] } )


# I want to get:

df4=pd.DataFrame({ 'col1':[1,0,0,1,1], 'col2':[1,0,0,1,1] } )
```

Where each cell in df4 is calculated by:

```py
if ( ( df1['colX'][Y] > df2['colX'][Y] ) or ( df1['colX'][Y] < df3['colX'][Y] ) ):
    df4['colX'][Y] = 1
else:
    df4['colX'][Y] = 0
```

In other words, if the cell value in df1 is not between the values in `df2` and `df3`, in the same position, set a flag.

This is for a function, so the number of row and columns (`X` and `Y`) is not fixed.

I could do this by looping through all the columns and rows, but that would be slower and not something I think a `pandas` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already done almost all of the work, you just need to translate it into pandas using broadcasting and boolean indexing

( df1['colX'][Y] > df2['colX'][Y] ) becomes (df1>df2)

`or` becomes`|`

```
((df1>df2)|(df1<df3))

    col1    col2
0   True    True
1   False   False
2   False   False
3   True    True
4   True    True

((df1>df2)|(df1<df3)).astype(int)

    col1    col2
0   1   1
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   1   1
4   1   1
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, you can accept the answer with the check mark next to the solution. Cheers